# Qt: How to display an hourglass on a QML Page while a lengthy C++ operation is executed in background

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Problem: A QML action must call a Q_INVOKABLE C++ function that takes some time to run.
When we do it the simple way: as soon as a user presses the Enter key, the method is called and the GUI freezes immediately while the code is executed, which is to be expected.

We'd like to update the GUI **first** (e.g. to display an hourglass) and then to execute the C++ method once the QML page has been updated.

(I imagine we've got to put a Qt event at the end of the Event Queue so it's processed **after** the others events that will update the QML page).

QML:

```
...
...
Keys.onEnterPressed: {
    MyCplusplusClass.myInvokableMethod(); 
}
..
```

C++:
class MyCplusplusClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

```
    ...
    Q_INVOKABLE void myInvokableMethod();
    ...
}
```

Now we want to run it asynchronously so the GUI won't freeze while it is executed. How is the best method to do that. I'll reproduce below the solution we're using, but I feel there is better to do (I'm not a Qt expert at all and would need some pointer).

QML:

```
...
property bool _displayHourglass;
...
Keys.onEnterPressed: {
    _displayHourglass = true ;
    MyCplusplusClass.asynchronousInvokableMethod();
}
...
...
Connections {
    target: MyCplusplusClass
    signal signalSynchronousMethodFinished
    onSignalSynchronousMethodFinished: {
        _displayHourglass = false ;
    }
}
...
Image {
    visible: _displayHourglass
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    source: "qrc:/images/icons/hourglass.png"
}
```

C++:

```
class MyCplusplusClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    Q_INVOKABLE void asynchronousInvokableMethod() {
        QTimer::singleShot(1, this, SLOT(synchronousMethod()));
    }
    ...
private slots:
    void synchronousMethod() {
        ...
        emit signalSynchronousMethodFinished() ;
    }
signals:
    ...
    signalSynchronousMethodFinished();
    ...
}
```

What would be a better solution, please?
I'd prefer to avoid the solution with a worker thread, it's okay for the GUI to freeze if there is an hourglass displayed.

Comment: CPU bound tasks are generally delegated to QThread, you can have signals when it started / finnished..

Comment: Yes, everything in the main thread, UI/UX, and your application will compete for resources. So, if you have an intensive operation that never backs off, you will cause the UI/UX to freeze. The alternative is to redesign your application to operate in steps so that you don't take 100% of the thread, and/or move your operation to another thread. Qt's QObject signal/slot mechanism can help you marshal results from another thread back to the main thread. Also, Qt has a built-in BusyIndicator but that will not function effectively if you are going to block the main thread.